# MySQL Get the second lowest row by id at every group

Tags: mysql, sql, join, min

I'm trying to get the second lowest row in my table from every Grouped. I've got already the lowest, but now I need the second lowest.
Sry for my bad english

Do somebody know a solution?

```
SELECT bestlellangaben 
FROM bestellangaben
JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(ID) AS newid 
    FROM bestellangaben
    WHERE SeitenID = 185
    GROUP BY grouping
) AS temp ON ID = temp.newid
```

[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFXfj.png)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer will probably depend on which one you're using.)

Comment: MySQL and sry for my inaccurate question

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a sophisticated way of doing this in MySQL, so here's are two brute force solutions...

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    bestellangaben  b
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        b.grouping,
        b.SeitenID,
        MIN(b.ID) AS MinID2
    FROM
        bestellangaben  b
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            b.grouping,
            b.SeitenID,
            MIN(b.ID) AS MinID
        FROM
            bestellangaben  b
        GROUP BY
            b.grouping,
            b.SeitenID
    )
        b_min
            ON  b_min.grouping = b.grouping
            AND b_min.SeitenID = b.SeitenID
            AND b_min.MinID    < b.ID
    GROUP BY
        b.grouping,
        b.SeitenID
)
    b_2min
        ON  b_2min.grouping = b.grouping
        AND b_2min.SeitenID = b.SeitenID
        AND b_2min.MinID2   = b.ID
WHERE
    b.SeitenID = 185
```

Or, using correlated sub-queries...

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    bestellangaben  b
WHERE
    b.SeitenID = 185
    AND (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                bestellangaben   lookup
            WHERE
                    lookup.grouping = b.grouping
                AND lookup.SeitenID = b.SeitenID
                AND lookup.ID       < b.ID
        )
        = 1
```

Comment: Use the answer from @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Thank your really much! But i have to say i dont understand it!

Answer (score 2):

Select the second ID in a correlated subquery for each group using LIMIT and OFFSET

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM bestellangaben b
WHERE b.ID = (
    SELECT b1.ID
    FROM bestellangaben b1
    WHERE b1.grouping = b.grouping
      AND SeitenID = 185
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
)
```

Here is another one, wich counts the ids that are lesser:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bestellangaben b
JOIN bestellangaben b1
    ON  b1.grouping = b.grouping
    AND b1.ID < b.ID
WHERE b.SeitenID = 185
  AND b1.SeitenID = 185
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING COUNT(b1.ID) = 1 -- one ID is lesser
```

Use the first one for a small number of big groups. Use the second one for a big number of small groups.

Comment: @Strawberry - The ops' own attempt was simply giving the "first item per group".  And the image attached 'implies' that the ID field is indeed a unique identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Is this sophisticated? I don't really know - but it's pretty fast...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bestellangaben;

CREATE TABLE bestellangaben
(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,SeitenId INT NOT NULL
,bestlellangaben VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,grouping TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO bestellangaben VALUES
(863 ,185, "CAN I/O & CAN PLC",0),
(864 ,185, "6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os",0),
(865 ,185, "G7" ,0),
(866 ,185, "10333000E" ,0),
(867 ,185, "CAN I/O & CAN PLC - RPM" ,1),
(868 ,185, "6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os (2x frequency input)" ,1),
(869 ,185, "G7" ,1),
(870 ,185, "103130100E" ,1),
(871 ,185, "CAN I/O & CAN PLC - Current In" ,2),
(872 ,185, "6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os (3x current input)" ,2),
(873 ,185, "G7",2),
(874 ,185, "103130100E", 2),
(875 ,185, "CAN I/O & CAN PLC - PWM Out",3),
(876 ,185, "6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os (6x PWM)", 3),
(877 ,185, "G7" ,3);

SELECT a.id
     , a.seitenId
     , a.bestlellangaben
     , a.grouping
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=grouping THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev:=grouping 
         FROM bestellangaben x
            , ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY grouping
            , id
     ) a
 WHERE rank = 2;

+-----+----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
| id  | seitenId | bestlellangaben                              | grouping |
+-----+----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
| 864 |      185 | 6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os                      |        0 |
| 868 |      185 | 6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os (2x frequency input) |        1 |
| 872 |      185 | 6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os (3x current input)   |        2 |
| 876 |      185 | 6 analog inputs. 8 I/Os (6x PWM)             |        3 |
+-----+----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: I'd go with "sophisticated", yes.  It mimics the behaviour of analytic functions, meaning that it can complete in a single scan of the table *(though without being able to take any short-cuts; it will have to enumerate every row, even when it gets beyond the target value)*.  I'd be intrigued as to how this performs against the correlated sub-query *(with LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)*.  I suspect that the more rows in each group the better the correlated sub-query will perform, but I have no idea if it will ever perform as well as this one.

Comment: I bet it knocks the socks off a correlated subquery

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT ID AS newid 
FROM bestellangaben
WHERE SeitenID = 185
ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1,1
```

The Limit 1,1 does the trick of getting the 2nd element when sorted in ascending by ID.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, an explanation is needed to make it to an answer.